# BindingList with int array updating a listbox?

Tags: c#, list, listbox, datasource, bindinglist

I have a BindingList like the follow:

```
private BindingList<int[]> sortedNumbers = new BindingList<int[]>();
```

Each entry is a int[6], now I wanted to bind it to a listbox so it updates it everytime a set of numbers is added to it.

```
listBox1.DataSource = sortedNumbers;
```

The result is the below text for each entry:

```
Matriz Int32[].
```

How do I format the output or change it so it prints the numbers of each entry set as they are generated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the `Format` event:

```
listBox1.Format += (o,e) => 
 { 
    var array = ((int[])e.ListItem).Select(i=>i.ToString()).ToArray();
    e.Value = string.Join(",", array);
 };
```

Comment: +1 interesting didnt know I had a format in there but the cast doesnt seem to work on the join.

Comment: Are you using .NET 4.0 or are you using an earlier version than that?

Comment: Pardon me ... I am tied to 3.5

Answer (score 0):

How about using IValueConverter in the ItemTemplate?

```
<ListBox x:Name="List1" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource  NumberConverter}}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

public class NumberConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is int[])
        {
            int[] intValues = (int[])value;
            return String.Join(",", intValues);
        }
        else return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Convert(value, targetType, parameter, culture);
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't notice that you are using winform. But at least I find another observable collection in your code: "BindingList<T>"